# RAML documentation doesn't display in API Console

Tags: api, documentation, raml

I have the below documentation defined in a RAML spec I'm developing:

```
#%RAML 0.8

title: API
version: 1.0
baseUri: http://localhost

#===============================================================
#  API documentation
#===============================================================

documentation:
  - title: Home
    content: | 
      This is an API.

#===============================================================
# API resource definitions
#=============================================================== 
...
```

However, when I try and view this documentation via the API console, I'm seeing a blank box like the below:

[image]

Any thoughts around why my text `This is an API.` is not displaying within the Home box?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried clicking on 'Home' ?

The fold/unfold arrow is probably inverted but the doc should be there.

Comment: Yes I have clicked (as you can see in the image the arrow is inverted down) but no documentation is show. Perhaps this is a bug in the console generation...

Comment: It's a bit counterintuitive, but [Fabien Kruba](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1621467/fabien-kruba) is right. You should click on the work 'Home', not on the arrow.